# Is there a way to expose ports on runtime in a K8S Deployment?

Tags: java, mongodb, kubernetes

I have a container in which a Java Process starts up a Mongo Daemon process on a random available port. Is there a way to tell a K8S Service about this port and expose it externally ?

Comment: Why random port? Can't you use a fixed port number?

Comment: @kiner_shah good point, I should know this but say you have a docker container with ubuntu base image, would all the usable ports be free ?

Comment: Most services use well known ports, so for user applications lots of ports are open unless you are running large number of applications in a single docker container on different ports - that's what I think at least.